# How to get the next element regardless of if it's a sibling or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using `$(elm).next().addClass( "currentStep" );` on element click, but once it hits the last sibling I want it to go over to the next div container.
How do I do that?

Here is [the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dxb3s33c/2/).

```js
function clicked(elm) {
  $(elm).removeClass("currentStep");
  $(elm).next().addClass("currentStep");
}
```

```css
.currentStep {
  border: 1px dashed #6e6e6e;
  background-color: rgba(217, 233, 244, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

<div class="single-task-widget">
  <div class="widget-header">
    <p>Section 1</p>
    <h4>Create</h4>
  </div>
  <button class="collapse-btn"><i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-angle-up"></i></button>
  <div class="task-wrapper collapsed">
    <ul class="task-list">
      <li onclick="clicked(this);" id="s1s1"><span>Click</span><b>File</b><span class="status"></span></li>
      <li onclick="clicked(this);" id="s1s2" class="currentStep"><span>Click</span><b>New</b><span class="status"></span></li>
      <li onclick="clicked(this);" id="s1s3" class=""><span>Select</span><b>International Paper</b><span class="status"></span></li>
      <li onclick="clicked(this);" id="s1s4" class=""><span>Select</span><b>Paper Size: A3</b><span class="status"></span></li>
      <li onclick="clicked(this);" id="s1s5" class=""><span>Type</span><b>72</b><span class="status"></span></li>
      <li onclick="clicked(this);" id="s1s6" class=""><span>Click</span><b>Ok</b><span class="status"></span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="single-task-widget">
  <div class="widget-header">
    <p>Section 2</p>
    <h4>Resize</h4>
  </div>
  <button class="collapse-btn"><i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-angle-up"></i></button>
  <div class="task-wrapper collapsed">
    <ul class="task-list">
      <li onclick="clicked(this);" id="s2s1"><span>Click</span><b>Image</b><span class="status"></span></li>
      <li onclick="clicked(this);" id="s2s2"><span>Click</span><b>Image Size</b><span class="status"></span></li>
      <li onclick="clicked(this);" id="s2s3"><span>Type</span><b>1000</b><span class="status"></span></li>
      <li onclick="clicked(this);" id="s2s4"><span>Type</span><b>800</b><span class="status"></span></li>
      <li onclick="clicked(this);" id="s2s5"><span>Click</span><b>Ok</b><span class="status"></span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can use indexing and `eq()` instead of `next()`

```
function clicked(elm) {

  var $tasks = $('.task-list li'),
    currentIndex = $tasks.index(elm);

  $tasks.eq(currentIndex + 1).addClass("currentStep")
  $(elm).removeClass("currentStep");


}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dxb3s33c/3/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

you nee to add a check to see if you are at the final sibling or "step" in the process, if so traverse up the DOM tree to the wrapper "section" get the next "section" and set the first "step" as active

something like this should work

```
function clicked(elm) {
    // remove for ALL to avoid duplicates if a step is skipped
    $('.currentStep').removeClass( "currentStep" );
      // will return 0 if it is the last
    if ($(elm).next().length) {
        $(elm).next().addClass( "currentStep" );
    } else {
        // get the wrapper and find the next -> set first as active
        $(elm).parents('.single-task-widget').next().find('.task-list li:first-child').addClass( "currentStep" )
    }
}
```